# bitcoinJ with createP2SHOutputScript

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoinj

I am trying to create multi-signature address for the each transaction.

```
Transaction tx = new Transaction(kit.params());
Script script = ScriptBuilder.createP2SHOutputScript(2, keysList);
```

Adress created and I can send coins to this address 
please see 
https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC/address/2NFeNLDC3928gAh9oagQnfdz25p5vdyE7gD

But, if I want to spend coins from this address 2NFeNLDC3928gAh9oagQnfdz25p5vdyE7gD
bitcoinJ cannot find it

```
kit.wallet().calculateAllSpendCandidates(true);
```

only addresses without P2S can found by calculateAllSpendCandidates.

Does any body know how to create addresses with multi-signature for the each output/input and find this into wallet by calculateAllSpendCandidates.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you have send balance to any multisig address like 2NFeNLDC3928gAh9oagQnfdz25p5vdyE7gD. You can't send money from this address, as this address does not exists in your wallet. To use this money, first you need to claim this amount, at any one address for which you create this escrow